# Force overflow hidden without container

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML and CSS (bare bones):

```css
.tall-element:before {
        height: 2000px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #000;
        width: 10px;
        display: block;
        content: " ";
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li class="element-i-want-do-use-to-hide">
    </li>
    <li class="tall-element">
    </li>
</ul>
```

This (intentionally) creates a line
I'd like the ability to set `overflow:hidden` to the `.element-i-want-do-use-to-hide` element, but I can't exactly do that.

I can set `overflow-y: hidden` to the `<ul>` and that will cause the line to break, which is the effect I'm looking for, except I'd like to apply that break to a neighboring element (in this case, the `.element-i-want-do-use-to-hide` element).

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I didn't quietly understand, providing a diagram/image of the intended result or explaining more would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```css
.tall-element:before {
    height: 2000px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 10px;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
}

.element-i-want-do-use-to-hide {
  position: relative;
}

.element-i-want-do-use-to-hide:before {
    height: 2000px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 10px;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li class="element-i-want-do-use-to-hide">
    </li>
    <li class="tall-element">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using overflow-y: auto on the containing unordered list and then setting the z-index of the other li tags to be higher than the tall-element